# How to do comparison among 8 columns of data with one another?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

How to do comparison among 8 columns of data with one another? I have to compare every column with every other column. Also i need to know : what is missing in one column and present in another and vice versa.

Comment: What kind of comparison? What does your data look like? We really need a lot more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Excel or some spreadsheet, sort the items in the same order and use your eyes.  If an item doesn't exist in a column, add a blank entry to the others to keep everything lined up.  It's slow and a pain, but it works.

Sort each column of data in the same order, then extract each to a separate file in Excel or a text file, or some common format.  Use an application such as BeyondCompare to compare two files at a time.  It will show mismatches between the two.  I don't think it can do more than two at a time, however.  It's not slow and usually works very nicely.